# How to write a Postgres UPDATE query with parameters specified as a list of values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to write a Postgres UPDATE query with parameters specified as a list of values, but I'm getting a syntax error. However very similar INSERT query works just fine.

```
Query giving an error

'update user set (username, firstname, lastname) values($1, $2, $3) where id = 3'


Similar query that works fine

'insert into user (id, position, firstname, lastname) values($1, $2, $3, $4) '
```

Comment: Yes, that is a syntax error, you cannot use a `VALUES` clause in that position. Have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#EXAMPLES

Comment: Are you really still on version 9.1?

Comment: You need to read about SQL.  `UPDATE user SET username=$1, firstname=$2, lastname=$3 WHERE id=3`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts  The syntax to whch you are referring is cumbersome that's why I was looking for a better one.

Comment: It is exactly the same amount of typing as the solution below, and it is universal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
update user set (username, firstname, lastname) = ($1, $2, $3) where id = 3
```

This is called ***column-list syntax*** of update statement in PostgreSQL.

Comment: For  reference sake, this is a Postgres extension that is not present in other SQLs.